# How to see entire root hdfs disk usage? (hadoop dfs -du / gets subfolders)

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs

We have perhaps not unsurprisingly given how fascinating big data is to the business, a disk space issue we'd like to monitor on our hadoop clusters.

I have a cron job running and it is doing just what I want except that I'd like one of the output lines to show the overall space used. In other words, in bash, the very last line of a "du /" command shows the total usage for all the subfolders on the entire disk. I'd like that behavior.

Currently when I run "hadoop dfs -du /", however, I get only the subdirectory info and not the overall total.

What's the best way to get this?
thank you so much to all you Super Stack Overflow people :).

Answer (score 1):

I just didn't understand the docs correctly! Here is the answer to get the total space used;

```
$ hadoop dfs -dus /
hdfs://MYSERVER.com:MYPORT/ 999
$ array=(`hadoop dfs -dus /`)
$ echo $array
hdfs://MYURL:MYPORT/
$ echo ${array[1]} ${array[0]}
999 hdfs://MYURL:MYPORT/
```

Reference; File System Shell Guide
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/file_system_shell.html#du
//edit; Also corrected the order of reporting to match the original.

Comment: This answer needs a revisit. The `hdaoop dfs` command and the option `-dus`both are deprecated now. `hdfs dfs -du -s -h /` would be a precise command to try as of the writing.

Answer (score 0):

> hadoop fs -du -s -h /path

This will give you the summary.

For the whole cluster you can try :

> hdfs dfsadmin -report

You may need to run this with HDFS user.

Comment: On RHEL, that doesn't work for me? I get an error? (elided tail part here)
    s -du -s  /
    du: Cannot access -s: No such file or directory.
    Found 2 items
    999  hdfs://MYURL/apps

Comment: On; $ hadoop version
 =>  Hadoop 1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107
Subversion git://ip-10-191-187-97/ on branch condor-branch-1 -r d4625cb994e0143f5f4b538f0f2f4a41ad6464a2
Compiled by jenkins on Mon May 20 02:25:14 EDT 2013
From source with checksum 295dfaf445332ed0c577a94795a1eaa9
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar

Comment: This command works fine for me. I am using Cloudera Distribution with CDH 4 & CDH 5. For overall cluster you could try : hdfs dfsadmin -report